# How do I view the rest of a partial class in a silverlight project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, partial-classes

So this is driving me nuts that I cannot see rest of the MainPage partial class in the MainPage.xaml.cs of my silverlight application.

I'm no longer having any coding issues, but is there a way to view it? I want to see the other partial class(es). I feel like I have no control of my code, and that I do not understand it...

PS: I know HTML5 >>> silverlight, but this is a corporate decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click the dropdown on your MainPage.xaml.cs you will see methods that are greyed out, these are the methods that you are looking for. If you have another partial class based on your MainPage they will be visible there also.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When Ctrl Key Pressed Click on Class name (MainPage for this instance) and you will see list of other partials. Not for just Silverlight projects.

Its a good way extending a class I think. When you manage well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should be in YourProject\obj\x86\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs

Comment: @LLL - if the answer helped, you can at least upvote it and finally accept it as "THE answer"

Comment: partial classes can be in generated codes but not always you may code another partial somewhere else [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)